# string.trim() in java for string containing a lot of white spaces - its length is returned as 1 instead of 0

Tags: java, trim

The following code does not work as expected:

```
public int countSegments(String s) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.trim().split(" ")));
    return (s.trim().split(" ")).length;
}
```

If s = "     ", then ideally it should return 0. But it returns 1 even though the array printed is empty. Could anybody please explain how 1 is the result? Please note that s here contains multiple spaces, not just 1 space. StackOverflow is not allowing to enter multiple spaces.

Comment: `"".split(" ")` will return a 1-element array containing `""`. Your expectations are not right.

Comment: i think it is expected.  java doc says " If the expression does not match any part of the input then the resulting array has just one element, namely this string.". Since you are using trim, your expression will not match.

Answer (score 0):

`split()` of `String` returns `new String[]{this}` if no match is found.
In your case, `s.trim()` returns `""` and `s.trim().split(" ")` returns `new String[]{""}`. `new String[]{""}` is an array with 1 length. If you execute the expression `System.out.println(s.trim().split(" ")[0].equals(""))` you will get `true`